# Do I need a script or a formula?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to have the formula look in Column A for not empty cells. (That part of the formula works fine.) Then return the name from Column B that's in the same row as the not empty cell.

Column A                      Column B
text/date                     Kelly

So if B has anything in it, tell me the name Kelly. I 've tried combining formulas, but I'm either not doing it correctly or maybe I need a script?

Here's the part that's working: =IF(A24="","don't meet","meet")
Of course, I want it to search the whole column, but I know for sure 24 has the text in the cell with a name so I was just playing around that line.

Comment: Hi Kelly, 

looks like a formula can achieve what you're looking for. Can you share a dummy document with data and expected result you're looking for so we can visualize what exactly you want to happen?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PCUy6kArqOEmGWb3svl4ocIn0RwREJFtirVhWqakG9g/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you include your expected result? I'm not sure if you want to get all the non-empty column B value with non-empty column A

Comment: Oh yes. So I want a list of names but only those names that have something typed in Column A. So Hungry, Sorry, Funny, Kelly.  I'm working with over 600 names in the original doc, but I only need the names with information in column A.  2/15 Kelly;

Answer (score 0):

Answer is based on the description and document you provided and should give you something to work with.

This formula simple checks the entire Column A and returns values from the corresponding row from Col B if the Cell from the Col A row is empty/blank.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA((IF(A1:A<>"",B1:B,"")))
```

Here are example screenshots of your example data + end result

[image]

Though I'm not entirely sure what you'd like to happen if A has values on them. This formula retains A if it has content but you could always change the *(A2:A="",B2:B,*`A2:A`*)* part of the formula if you want something else to happen if A is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try, I put it in your sheet in the green area.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A15 = "", "", B1:B15))
```

Arrayformula applies the IF function to the entire range.  So substitute A1:A15 with what ever the whole range is, A1:A600   or A1:A if you want to do the whole column.  Make srue the second column has the same values but with B.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [filter()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197) to filter your Column B if both column A and column B is not empty.

**Formula:**

`=filter(B1:B,A1:A<>"",B1:B<>"")`

**Output:**

[image]